How in OOTB spartacus the CMS pages, components are rendered?
Say someone lands on the /checkout/delivery-address page of the checkout journey. How the occ call is made to main page https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/apparel-uk-spa/cms/pages?pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=%2Fcheckout%2Fdelivery-address&lang=en&curr=USD.
Can someone outline the details of the flow in spartacus. Which components, configs, services, connectors, adapters are responsible to make this initial call to get the contentslots and components?
I tried checking the OOTB spartacus code but somehow not able to connect the dots.

Checkout is a complicated example, as it has its own additional mapping/routing configuration: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/
